# NGX bluetooth printer not working

Tags: android

I am using NGX bluetooth printer in my android project and I am able to print the text on the printer via bluetooth, but I cannot use printer specific codes as

```
mBtp.printTextLine("\n\n\n\n");
```

provided by them in demo code.